# Vertically align justified inline-block elements inside a container

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-align

I know that this questions has been asked several times, but I couldn't find a solution for this specific situation.

So, here's what I have:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/db0onh6c/1/)

Basically it's a list of rows:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>
            <span>element1</span>
            <span>element2</span>
            <span>element3</span>
            <span>element4</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <span>element1</span>
            <span>element2</span>
            <span>element3</span>
            <span>element4</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the `span` elements are all `inline-blocks` and `label` has `text-align: justify`.

Everything works as expected, and as I want it to, but the vertical alignment. All the items are attached to the top, kind of. I thought it was the usual inline-block annoyance of the empty line afterward, but I tried setting the `font-size` to 0, or removing the white space and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have to do with the `line-height` – somehow it makes that pseudo element take up additional space. You can mitigate the effects a little bit by setting `line-height:0` for the `label` and the `li`, and then a `line-height:1` for `.product-row-price` again … but that still doesn’t look that good, it still leaves some space at the bottom. (And a lower line-height will make the text in `.product-row-price` overlap.)

I think a better solution would be a negative margin-bottom for the label, and overflow set to hidden:

```
.product-row-label {
    margin-bottom: -1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* rest of existing styles */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/db0onh6c/7/

FYI: `div` in `span` is invalid HTML – so you should replace those divs inside of `.product-row-price` with spans and make them block.

Still doesn’t look to pretty though, because the different widths of the content in the first and third column makes the whole thing look uneven, so the content in the second column doesn’t align horizontally. (Although with a set width for the first and last column that could be avoided, if you’re ok with a little space at the right of the “shorter” values in the third column – something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/db0onh6c/8/)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. You're right about the `div`.
The last solution you propose seems to work pretty well. I'd just do the last column a bit larger and setting `text-align: right` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to set property `display: table;` to `<label>` elements and `display:table-cell;` to your `<span>`elements. This fix element to display as a `<table>` html element. Just fix padding and margin display properly.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/db0onh6c/5/)

Comment: I tried this solution before, and it's a nice one, but this way I lose the justified alignment. You suggest to simulate it with paddings and margins?